# Disable AJAX on checkout for WooCommerce

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I'd like to ask how I could disable AJAX at the checkout page (where you enter shipping and billing information) and that instead of using AJAX to update the cart summary based on your location, it would update by doing a natural refresh.

Currently the cart summary would update itself without reloading the page whenever the user switches their location via shipping location. I'd like to remove that AJAX and just have the page reload with the updated information.

I'm not too sure what sort of codes or direction I should be pointing at but I'm ready to provide whatever details necessary. Just let me know! Thank you!!

Comment: Why are you trying to remove Ajax?  Under Woocommerce->Settings->Products->Add to cart there is a section to disable Ajax but it may not be what your looking for.

Comment: @Robert Lee I'm trying to remove AJAX because it's overwriting my translations. I've been looking for ways to have the updated content via AJAX become translated each time so instead, I'd rather just remove it and have the page reload with the proper content that's translated each time. Unfortunately, disable AJAX using the method you spoke of only disables the AJAX when adding products to your cart.

Answer (score 13):

All WooCommerce strings are properly localized with `wp_localize_script` so I would think you could correctly translate them by creating the appropriate .po/.mo file, but I confess to not having a lot of experience with translations. For reference: all available language packs are [at Github](http://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce-language-packs/tree/master/packages) and you might also want to read the [documentation](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-localization/).

Anyway, the checkout scripts are all in `checkout.js`. Like any script you can dequeue it via [`wp_dequeue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script) as long as you know the handle.

```
function so_27023433_disable_checkout_script(){
    wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-checkout' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'so_27023433_disable_checkout_script' );
```

Comment: What happens exactly when you denqueue a script?

Comment: It doesn't get loaded on the front-end. Refer to the codex article.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue, and instead of remove the entire script, i went to see when the event is created, and i found this.

```
$( document.body ).bind( 'update_checkout', this.update_checkout );
```

After reading a little, i found that I will not be able to unbind because of the namespace, so i hooked up on the `on` event and since i can't prevent default i stoped the propagation of the event.

and these solved my problem.

```
jQuery(document.body).on('update_checkout', function(e){
    //e.preventDefault();
    //e.stopPropagation();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    //console.log(e);
});
```

Comment: That's a good idea. Hopefully your event is triggered before the WC default one otherwise I think the e.stopImmediatePropagation will stop the remaining hooked functions but not the one already executed. Obviously you can check the moment the WC hooks its function and you can hook your function just earlier. So yes, I think it would work.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the logic of checkout.js source code you will notice that these AJAX actions related to editing the billing|shipping addresses can be safely disabled by changing the checkout form's class name. 
Yes, I know, it's that simple. So instead of `form.checkout` make it `form.checkout1` where `.checkout1` is just an imaginary class name (it doesn't have to be real/existent).

Here is a sample code that might help you understand what's required:

```
var default_class = 'checkout';
var mask_class = 'checkout1';

// hijack the form's AJAX by changing form's default class name
$('form.'+default_class).addClass(mask_class).removeClass(default_class);

// restore the original class name whenever you want it
$('form.'+mask_class).addClass(default_class).removeClass(mask_class);
```

Please note that this is a hack which it's not documented. They may however change the checkout form functionality at any time so keep that in mind. I can confirm it works on WC 2.6.14 and probably in earlier versions too.

Comment: One more thing about this approach: make sure that you revert the default class on body.checkout_error otherwise you might encounter an JS error because the submit_error function of checkout.js will evaluate the $( 'form.checkout' ).offset() which would trigger a ReferenceError exception.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem: loaded checkout scripts at a [quote list checkout](https://woocommercequoteplugin.com). The scripts where loaded through another plugin again ([WooCommerce Germanized](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-germanized/)).

Our solution is a more explicit one:

- Configure a custom field on the page, you don't want the checkout script be loaded.

And than:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myprefix_dequeue_woocommerce_checkout', 10000);

function myprefix_dequeue_woocommerce_checkout() {
  if (get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'disable_woocommerce_checkout_scripts')) {
    wp_dequeue_script('wc-checkout');
    wp_dequeue_script('wc-gzd-checkout');
    wp_dequeue_script('wc-gzdp-checkout');
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

One way to not disable checkout.js.

First it is possible that checkout.min.js is loaded instead of checkout.js.

Then comment thoses 2 lines :

```
update_checkout:function(){
    //b.reset_update_checkout_timer(),
    //b.updateTimer=setTimeout(b.update_checkout_action,"5")
},
```

Then your checkout page will be ajax free!

Comment: I don't know if this would work or not, but it's poor practice to edit the code in third-party libraries, such as plugins. It can have unexpected results, often adds considerably to maintenance time and will be lost during standard update procedures.