# WooCommerce - checkout - AJAX billing address check error

Tags: ajax, woocommerce, checkout

I have a problem with WooCommerce's checkout form (WooCommerce version 2.4.7). I sell a physical object and I have guest purchases enabled (with an option to register). I skip the cart, because it's unnecessary in my case. Anyway, when I input the billing address, at the end, AJAX call to `checkout/?wc-ajax=update_order_review` is made and the data returned from call is as follows:

```
{"result":"success","messages":"","reload":"false","fragments":{".woocommerce-checkout-review-order-table"
:"<table class=\ ... "}
```

The `result` is `success`, but the fields get emptied and the user is therefore prompted to input the address again and again ... with no success. I use the very well known Avada template and I don't really know, where to start debugging. I don't think it's the template issue.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who encountered this kind of problem, the solution seems to be to not to include the `checkout.js` file, which takes care of "AJAXy" stuff on Checkout page. You then have to do the input checks yourself.

The solution: [Disable AJAX on checkout for WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27033642/3631997)

Have a nice day!