# Woocommerce wc-ajax returns html response

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

The problem is in the checkout page, "Your Order" section is always grayed out and spinner is loading forever.

I turned off <strike>https</strike>, Cloudflare, All the Plugins, Activated default theme, same behavior persisted.

I tried to debug what is happening, when i reach the checkout page through Chrome Dev, Network tab:

an XHR POST request gets sent to /checkout/?wc-ajax=update_order_review

This is where it gets weird, the response that is returned with code 200 is actually an HTML response with the same page rather than JSON object, and the reponse headers are:

```
Request URL:https://alpha.seniorinafashion.com/checkout/?wc-ajax=update_order_review
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 
Remote Address:104.31.91.108:443
Response Headers
cache-control:no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
cf-ray:3312009e9e431a99-DUS
content-encoding:br
content-type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
date:Tue, 14 Feb 2017 16:47:31 GMT
expires:Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
link:<https://alpha.seniorinafashion.com/?p=2724>; rel=shortlink
link:<https://alpha.seniorinafashion.com/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
server:cloudflare-nginx
set-cookie:woocommerce_cart_hash=771886deccd483983b22b6a8ac26f76e; path=/
set-cookie:wp_woocommerce_session_d3fe2e799745c6650de3e94ad8c9e5b5=59cfc776e38750ac597b0cc8396dca00%7C%7C1487260661%7C%7C1487257061%7C%7C887c63ae5a0e78a8c86f7622f03cd2d2; expires=Thu, 16-Feb-2017 15:57:41 GMT; Max-Age=169810; path=/
set-cookie:woocommerce_items_in_cart=1; path=/
set-cookie:woocommerce_cart_hash=771886deccd483983b22b6a8ac26f76e; path=/
set-cookie:wp_woocommerce_session_d3fe2e799745c6650de3e94ad8c9e5b5=59cfc776e38750ac597b0cc8396dca00%7C%7C1487260661%7C%7C1487257061%7C%7C887c63ae5a0e78a8c86f7622f03cd2d2; expires=Thu, 16-Feb-2017 15:57:41 GMT; Max-Age=169810; path=/
set-cookie:woocommerce_items_in_cart=1; path=/
status:200
x-frame-options:SAMEORIGIN
x-pingback:https://alpha.seniorinafashion.com/xmlrpc.php
Request Headers
:authority:alpha.seniorinafashion.com
:method:POST
:path:/checkout/?wc-ajax=update_order_review
:scheme:https
accept:*/*
accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, br
accept-language:en-US,en;q=0.8
content-length:836
content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
cookie:__cfduid=dcd5da450805c7fb21259f27cb677e8b51487087855; woocommerce_items_in_cart=1; woocommerce_cart_hash=771886deccd483983b22b6a8ac26f76e; wp_woocommerce_session_d3fe2e799745c6650de3e94ad8c9e5b5=59cfc776e38750ac597b0cc8396dca00%7C%7C1487260661%7C%7C1487257061%7C%7C887c63ae5a0e78a8c86f7622f03cd2d2
origin:https://alpha.seniorinafashion.com
referer:https://alpha.seniorinafashion.com/checkout/
user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
x-requested-with:XMLHttpRequest
Query String Parameters
view source
view URL encoded
wc-ajax:update_order_review
Form Data
view source
view URL encoded
security:47743ef2c2
payment_method:cod
country:DE
state:
postcode:
city:
address:
address_2:
s_country:DE
s_state:
s_postcode:
s_city:
s_address:
s_address_2:
post_data:billing_first_name=&billing_last_name=&billing_company=&billing_email=&billing_phone=&billing_country=DE&billing_address_1=&billing_address_2=&billing_postcode=&billing_city=&billing_state=&account_password=&shipping_first_name=&shipping_last_name=&shipping_company=&shipping_country=DE&shipping_address_1=&shipping_address_2=&shipping_postcode=&shipping_city=&shipping_state=&order_comments=&shipping_method%5B0%5D=flat_rate%3A1&payment_method=cod&terms-field=1&_wpnonce=794e840694&_wp_http_referer=%2Fcheckout%2F
shipping_method[0]:flat_rate:1
```

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27023433/disable-ajax-on-checkout-for-woocommerce

Comment: thanks alot, thats a nice work around, ill use it until i figure out the issue itself

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the exact same issue, but it goes away when I disable permalinks. After disabling permalinks I get expected JSON responses.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using **custom** woocommerce ajax endpoints (wc-ajax), you can use [wp_send_json](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_send_json/) function.

### Example:

Functions handling custom endpoint in `functions.php`:

```php
function mytheme__wc_cart_items_count_html(){
    $data = ['cart_item_count' => 2];
    exit($data);
}

function mytheme__wc_cart_items_count_json(){
    $data = ['cart_item_count' => 2];
    wp_send_json($data);
}
```

### How to register custom endpoint:

Add to your `functions.php`:

```php
add_action('wc_ajax_cart_item_count','mytheme__wc_cart_items_count_json');
```

### Endpoint URL:

`http://<hostname>/?wc-ajax=cart_item_count`